# Convert float to NSString using custom format? ("xx:yy")

Tags: ios, string, floating-point

I'm getting a JSON string back from a web service I'm using, one of the items is a float, which is formatted like this: "1.2".
But I actually want to make it show like a time number, so like this: "01:20".

What would be the easiest way of doing this?

I thought about converting the float to a string and then splitting it into 2 pieces

```
timeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", timeValue];
NSArray *tmpArr = [timeValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *tmpFirst = (NSString *)[tmpArr objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tmpSecond = (NSString *)[tmpArr objectAtIndex:0];
```

But somehow when I convert it, it returns me a negative number

> NSLog(@"timeValue: %@", timeValue);
>
> timeValue: -1.99

Comment: Just *replace* the "." with a ":"? I am not use what your stuff in the post has to do with the logged time value... also *passing in NSString to a format expecting a float ("f") will lead to odd results*. Please focus on *one* issue, and the issue posted (in the title).

Comment: That would just give me "1:2", while I want to display it as "01:20", so I would have to add 2 extra zeros.
The value returned is an amount in time, but it's formatted as a float

Comment: Ahh, indeed. In any case, heed the second part of the comment. The way I would do it then, without better knowledge, would be to get the `float` representing the input string (search SO for this process) and then use `format("%02d:%02d", (int)f, (int)(f * 100))` where `f` is the `float` value previously obtained. In the posted code, `timeValue` is of type `NSString` (or something "assignable"), which is not a `float`.

Comment: Uh, pst, you want to post that as an answer? Because it's right. The way to get a float from an NSString, btw, is to use NSString's handy `floatValue` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line.

```
timeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", timeValue];
```

I think timeValue is of type `NSString` if not then why are you using same variable twice. 
It should be like

```
timeValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", timeValueFloat];
```

Comment: timeValue was a variable passed by the function, so just re-using that one.

I found out that I could use tmpValue = [timeValue stringValue];, which game me the string value.